# Gmail blocking inline css properties

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I am creating an email template and i am mostly  using inline css but at some places even my inline css not working when i receive this email in gmail. It is working perfectly for yahoo but not for gmail.
Here is an example

```
<div class="etitle" style="float:left; padding-top:5px; width:58%; margin-left:20px;">
```

These css properties are working in browser and also in mailchimp but when i send email then these css properties are not working in gmail.
Why Gmail blocking these css properties?
I ll need little guidance about this

Comment: Have you checked that it is not a setting you have made in the Gmail client?

Comment: Yes checked and also i test this template with other gmail accounts with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style email sent to Gmail using inline  blocks and standard CSS. Most CSS selectors, attributes, and media-queries are supported. Unsupported CSS properties and selectors may be ignored by Gmail.

See the reference guide for a complete list of [supported CSS properties and queries](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css).

**Example**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .colored {
        color: blue;
      }
      #body {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
        .colored {
          color:red;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='body'>
      <p>Hi Pierce,</p>
      <p class='colored'>
        This text is blue if the window width is
        below 500px and red otherwise.
      </p>
      <p>Jerry</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

See also: a [complete breakdown of the CSS support](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for the most popular mobile, web and desktop email clients on the planet (from Campaign Monitor).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help, But i am still thinking why inline css not working. It is working at some places but not at few

Comment: In my experience, all the clients work differently, so I'm not surprised that the inline style does not always work. I suggest you follow the official Gmail directions.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you!